# How to navigate to sections(divs) on one web page?

Tags: html, css

It's a one page navigation with three sections. The navigation wont go the `div`s , it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

I wasn't sure if I need to add JS? The `div`s are there and are working properly but the navigation won't navigate to those sections...

```
<div class="nav" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about" id="ab">About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="ab">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" id="ab">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Do your divs have IDs matching those in your links? Can you post the entire source of your page?

Answer (score 2):

1) the href must point to the id of another element. if you have `<a href="#somelink">` you must have an element with an id attribute of `id='somelink'`.

2) id's must be unique. you cannot have more than one element with the same id. all of your links have the same  id.

Answer (score -4):

```
<div class="nav" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about" id="about">About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted his question. He meant that there are already another divs where he wants to navigate to while clicking the li elements he had mentioned. What you wrote is not correct in this case since on clicking it takes to the li only